# Keeping track of path while recursively going through branches (more info in description )- Using Tcl

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tcl

Background:

- Writting script in Tcl
- Running the script using a tool called [IDSBatch](http://www.agnisys.com/release/docs/ids/IDesignSpec.html?IDSBatch.html) from linux (centos) terminal

I have a system (.rdl file) that contains blocks, groups and registers.

Blocks can contain other blocks, groups, or registers. Whereas groups can only have registers and registers stand alone.

The problem I am having is I want to print out the "address" of each register i.e the name of the block(s), group and register associated with that specific register. For example:

```
               ______Block (a)______
               |                   |                
           Block (b)            reg(bob)
           |     |
    group(tall) group(short)
   |       |              |
reg(bill) reg(bobby)     reg(burt)
```

In the end the output should be something along the lines of:

reg one:    a.bob

reg two:    a.b.tall.bill

reg three:  a.b.tall.bobby

reg four:   a.b.short.burt

The true problem comes from the fact that blocks can contain blocks. So the system will not always have one to three levels (one level would be Block--reg, two levels would be Block--Block--reg or Block ---group---reg and so on...)

I was leaning to some sort of recursive solution, where I would access the element say a block and get all of it's children (groups,blocks and regs) then I would use the same function to access it's children (unless it's a register).  This way it can take care of any combination blocks groups and registers but then I'm stuck on how to keep track of the address of a specific register.

Thank you for taking the time in reading this and would appreciate any input or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list for doing that.

Starting with an empty list, you append all address parts to it. If you come across a register, you can then construct the path from front to back. After every level of recursion, you remove the last element to get rid of the part you handled.

Example: you just came across the register `bill`. Then, your list is `a` -> `b` ->`tall`. To get the address, you iterate over the list and concatenate the nodes together, then appending `bill` to the resulting string.

So, your recursion function would be somewhat like

- If the currently handled element is a register: Reconstruct the path.
- If the currently handled element is not a register: Append the path element to the list, call the function with that list and remove the last element of that list.

Comment: This is great thank you! (don't have enough rep to upvote yet :P)

Comment: @Diiice: even if you can't upvote, you can still accept the answer by clicking the check mark. This shows that the answer is useful and gives Abrixas2 a small amount of reputation.